# Java tunnel and tcp proxy

Tags: java, tcp, proxy

I need to tunnel through a tcp proxy.  Within Java, the proxy types are only socks, direct or HTTP.  So in the example below a socket is being created then the proxy object is being created from the `socketAddress` and the type is socks.
How can I specify the proxy is TCP?

```
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("socks.example.com", 1080);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
    Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
    InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress("server.example.org", 1234);
    try {
        socket.connect(dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isValidated;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a DIRECT proxy to Localhost on the port you set up to tunnel to the destination.  For example if your tunnel is set up to go from 4000 (Local) to 3389 (on the host you really want to connect to) the destination is Localhost, 1000, proxy type Direct.  See [SSH tunneling via JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850188/ssh-tunneling-via-jsch)

Comment: Can this be done without SSH?  Do you have a simple sample you could provide?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried.  My larger point was that what you're doing is tunneling and what you were trying was a proxy which are different things.  If it's a tunnel, then your application is blissfully unaware of how the data gets from one machine to the other, it just needs to be told where to connect.

Comment: Perhaps my word of tunneling was misused.  Why doesn't java support tcp proxys, why only socks and http?  I need to connect to a tcp proxy server.  I guess that's my issue, but java doesn't allow that method.  Any ideas?