# Double hop SSH connection: connection reset

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, portforwarding

I'am tring to do a double hop SSH in java with jsch. it's something like this :
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DAL0.png)

I face a connection reset issue when I connect to the second session.

Here is the code :

```
String user=user; String host=host; String pswd=pass;
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session= jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(pswd);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
System.out.println("Connecting to host1 ");
session.connect();


lport=2248;
rhost= rhost;
rport= 22;
int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
String user2=user;
String pswd2= pswd;
Session session2=jsch.getSession(user2, "localhost", assinged_port);
session2.setPassword(pswd2);

session2.setConfig(config);
System.out.println("Connecting to rhost via localhost:" + assinged_port);
session2.connect();


Channel channel = session2.openChannel("exec");     
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sh run");
channel.setInputStream(null);
ByteArrayOutputStream errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(errorStream);           
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
channel.setOutputStream(out);           
channel.connect();       
    
while(true){                     
  if(channel.isClosed()){
      System.out.println("exit-status: "+ channel.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }            
}
String result =new String(out.toByteArray());           
channel.disconnect();
```

Here is the resulting error :

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)

I don't know what I do wrong and how to join the second server.

Also tried the solution of this question -> [SSH tunneling via JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850188/ssh-tunneling-via-jsch)

but I got the same error "connection reset" on the second connection

Thanks in advance for your help and advises !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH tunneling via JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850188/ssh-tunneling-via-jsch)

Comment: @m4rc0s thanks for your answer
no, it doesn't answer, I tried the solution and I still get the same error "connection reset" on the second connection.