# Springboot FTP over SSH tunnelling

Tags: spring-boot, sftp, jsch, ssh-tunnel

I need to use SpringBoot (2.7.x) SFTP Adapter (spring-integration-sftp) to estabilish SFTP file transfer over SSH tunnelling.

The solution i've found (based on [SSH tunneling via JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850188/ssh-tunneling-via-jsch)) is to create a SSH connection via JSch and then to use spring SFTP adapter to connect the JSch session via port forwarding, hence:

1. JSch session between remotehost:22 and localhost:1234
2. SFTP Adapter to localhost:1234

I'm wondering if there is some better/other way to achieve this for example with a proper configuration of Spring SFTP Adapter (some example?) or with some other Springboot library that gives this feature out of the box.

Comment: `spring-integration-sftp` already uses `JSch` under the hood. It looks like you're confusing ftp and sftp. These are completely different things and SFTP is not FTP-over-ssh

Comment: Sorry, it was my typos. I edited my answer. The connection i'm trying to estabilish over the SSH tunnel uses SFTP protocol. My question is precisely due to spring-integration-sftp is based on JSch and maybe there is some better way to do what described

Comment: Not sure if it does all you need but have you looked at Camel SFTP: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/sftp-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration ?

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this... You shouldn't need to "tunnel" the SFTP into SSH by yourself as it is how SFTP just works, no other choice. I'm not familiar with spring-integration-sftp but as it has been said, it implements JSch which has everything you need for SFTP-connection. Just check the examples online...